# Ссылка на объект(с#)

Tags: c#

Никак не могу понять как ссылаться на другой объект. Форма 1 имеет datagridView(ReadOnle = true), если на форме 2 user сделает всё необходимое , то у datagridView с первой формы, должно поменяться свойство ReadOnly на False. Прошу помочь реализовать это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаешь так в первой форме - public void readOff (){
datagridview1.readonly = false;
}

Вторую вызываешь так

private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2 f2 = new form2();
            f2.Show(this);//передается ссылка на родительскую форму
        }

Теперь во 2 форме

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1 f1 = this.Owner as form1;
        f1.readOff();
        this.Close();
    }

Писал с телефона, так что сори за ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Слишком мало информации. Всё зависит от того как вы работаете со второй формой.

Если 2я форма вызывается модально, то после её закрытия, можно делать проверки. По результатам которых, активировать таблицу.

Если форма не модальная, опять же, либо вешаете событие на закрытие, и делаете проверки уже после закрытия. Либо через конструктор связываете 2ю и 1ю формы, и во 2й уже, по результатам проверок, активировать таблицу 1й.

И вообще этих самых способов 1 миллион + 100500. А какой использовать, уже дело вашего воображения.